# I need to change the color space to find the contour but I couldn't solve my problem

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I understood the error I got, I need to change the color space of the variable to gray, then I won't get the error, but I couldn't solve this problem, so I can't go to the next stage in my project. I'm posting the error I got below:

```py
error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\contours.cpp:197: error:
 (-210:Unsupported format or combination of formats)
 [Start]FindContours supports only CV_8UC1 images when mode != CV_RETR_FLOODFILL otherwise supports CV_32SC1 images only in function 'cvStartFindContours_Impl'
```

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("s.jpg")

while True:
    # ret, frame = cap.read()
    # frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
    
    # print(frame.shape)    # 480,640
    
    ycrbc = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCrCb)
    
    minYCrCb = np.array([0,140,90],np.uint8)
    maxYCrCb = np.array([230,170,120],np.uint8)
    imgeYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
    skinRegionYCrCb = cv2.inRange(imgeYCrCb,minYCrCb,maxYCrCb)
    skinYCrCb = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = skinRegionYCrCb)
    median_ycrcb = cv2.medianBlur(skinYCrCb, 3)
    
    _, esik = cv2.threshold(median_ycrcb, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    median_binary = cv2.medianBlur(esik, 7)
    
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(median_binary, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(median_binary, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in contours]
    max_index = np.argmax(areas)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[max_index])

    print(x, y, x+w, y+h)
    
    cv2.imshow("ycrbc",ycrbc)
    cv2.imshow("skinYCrCb",median_ycrcb)
    cv2.imshow("binary goruntu", esik)
    cv2.imshow("median_binary", median_binary)
    
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        break
    
# cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I worked on this picture:

[image]

If you can solve my problem by changing the color space here, I would really appreciate it, I searched a lot, but I couldn't find it or I'm missing something, it would be great if you could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

You have to use a single channel input in findContours function.
Changing your input to "gray", which is single channel, should fix this.